# Change payment gateway data sent to product description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I have a payment gateway for woocommerce, but in the product name of the products in the payment gateway dashboard the product name is received right as the code below.

Product name: Apple AirPods
Description: Wireless device used to bla bla

What i receive: Apple AirPods

**What i want:** want to show the product description next to the product name with w dash - between them as below;

Apple AirPods - Wireless device used to bla bla

The code that sends the product name only and works fine here is it:

```
/**
     * Process the payment and return the result.
     * @param  int $order_id
     * @return array
     */
    public function process_payment($order_id) {
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        $order_items = array();
        //get order items date(DateTime::ISO8601)
        $time_stamp = time() + $this->payment_expiry * 60 * 60;
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
            $product = $item->get_product();
            $item_data ['itemId'] = $product->get_sku() ? $product->get_sku() : $item->get_product_id();
            $item_data ['description'] = $product->get_name();
            $item_data ['quantity'] = $item->get_quantity();
            $item_data ['price'] = wc_format_decimal($product->get_price(), 2);
            $order_items[] = $item_data;
        }
        //send request to fawry to create charge
        $chargeRequest = array(
            'merchantRefNum' => $order_id,
            'merchantCode' => $this->merchant_code,
            'customerProfileId' => $order->get_customer_id(),
            'customerMobile' => $order->get_billing_phone(),
            'customerEmail' => $order->get_billing_email(),
            'paymentMethod' => "PAYATFAWRY",
            'amount' => WC()->cart->total,
            'currencyCode' => $order->get_currency(),
            "description" => $this->description,
            'chargeItems' => $order_items,
            'paymentExpiry' => date('c', $time_stamp),
            'signature' => hash('sha256', $this->merchant_code . $order_id . $order->get_customer_id() . 'PAYATFAWRY' . WC()->cart->total . $this->secure_key),
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line, and it should give the desired effect I believe.

```
$item_data ['description'] = $product->get_name();
```

To this

```
$item_data ['description'] = $product->get_name() . " - " . $product->get_description();
```

Comment: Seems to be the right answer but i tested it but it doesn't work still the name only appears.

Comment: @MagedMohamed Do you know if there are other fields that the API is looking for? Perhaps a name field?

Comment: Nope There isn't but i think the issue is in the line before here: 

            `$item_data ['itemId'] = $product->get_sku() ? $product->get_sku() : $item->get_product_id();`

It affects the value of the `$product->get_name()`

Comment: Can you make it the first line to get the product ID only without the sku, then the 2nd line to get the product description and lets see what will happen.

Comment: Ahh, then it the "ID".

`$item_data ['itemId'] = $product->get_sku() ? $product->get_sku() : $item->get_product_id() . " - " . $product->get_description();`

Comment: Sorry i want the first line to get the product ID only, and then the 2nd line get the name next to the description, don't want the description next to the id in the first line

Comment: `$item_data ['itemId'] = $product->get_id()`


`$item_data ['description'] = $product->get_name() . " - " . $product->get_description();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200913/discussion-between-maged-mohamed-and-robertc).

Comment: it worked like that was my issue, can you please help in this its the same question but with different way:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59456893/send-payment-gateway-woocommerce-producct-description-next-to-product-name