# Send payment gateway woocommerce producct description next to product name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to send the

```
function getProductsJson($order,$options) {
    $stupid_mode = $options['stupid_mode'];
        $items=$order->get_items();
        $arr = [];
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $data = $item->get_data();

            $arr[] = [
                'productSKU' => $data['product_id'],
                'description' => $data['name'],
                'quantity' => $data['quantity'],
                'price' => $data['total'] / $data['quantity'],
            ];
    }
}
```

Here in this part:

```
'description' => $data['name'],
```

I want it to send product description next to product name as example below:

*Product Name - Product Description*

How can achieve this ?

Best Regards

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. You have this index. You have this pr_name. What the problem? What do you want?

Comment: My question is that this part of code sends the name of the product in the payment gateway request, i want it to send the product description next to the product name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need product description saved in $content, you can get this by Product_ID, and then add this to your array:

```
function getProductsJson($order,$options) {
  $stupid_mode = $options['stupid_mode'];
  $items=$order->get_items();
  $arr = [];
  foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $data = $item->get_data();
    $product_description = get_post( $data['product_id'] )->post_content;
    $arr[] = [
            'productSKU' => $data['product_id'],
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'description' => $product_description,
            'quantity' => $data['quantity'],
            'price' => $data['total'] / $data['quantity'],
    ];
  }
}
```

Or if you need built-in woocommerce product description, try this:

```
function getProductsJson($order,$options) {
  $stupid_mode = $options['stupid_mode'];
  $items=$order->get_items();
  $arr = [];
  foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $data = $item->get_data();
    $product_instance = wc_get_product( $data['product_id'] );
    $product_full_description = $product_instance->get_description();
    $product_short_description = $product_instance->get_short_description();
    $arr[] = [
            'productSKU' => $data['product_id'],
            'name' => $data['name'], // or $data['description']
            'description' => $product_full_description, // or $product_short_description
            'quantity' => $data['quantity'],
            'price' => $data['total'] / $data['quantity'],
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: The first option works like a charm i have tested it and its working, or you prefere to use the 2nd one which is the built in woocommerce ?, but please we don't need an item to store the name as   'name' => $data['name'], we need the 'description' => $product_description, to have both name at first then the description next to it and separated with this symbol " - " so we just need it to be the result as this: 

product name - product description

I tried:             'description' => $data['name'] . $product_description,

What do you think and how can i separate them with a symbol " - "

Comment: what do you think of this:             'description' => $data['name'] .' - ' . $product_full_description, with the 2nd answer

Comment: Yes, really: you need just to concatenate the string. Like in your second comment